# SwiftUI DragGesture does not terminate when .onChanged is present

Tags: ios, swiftui, gesture, drag

I'm attempting to drag a view (the `ZStack` below) using the `dragPiece` gesture in the following code. If I have the `.onChanged` modifier commented out, this code works fine, in the sense that the view ends up repositioned. But when `.onChanged` is uncommented and active, the drag gesture seems to get stuck, repeatedly printing out the same `width` and `height` values, and the `.onEnded` modifier is never executed. This seems like it should be straightforward, so clearly I'm missing something. Any help will be appreciated.

```
struct PieceView: View {
    var id: String
    @State private var orientation: Int
    @State private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State var selected = false
    var dragPiece: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                dragOffset = value.translation
                print("width: \(dragOffset.width), height: \(dragOffset.height)")
            }
            .onEnded{ value in
                print("\(id) dragged")
                dragOffset = value.translation
                print("width: \(dragOffset.width), height: \(dragOffset.height)")
            }
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(id + "\(orientation)")
            Image("boardSquare")
                .padding(0)
                .gesture(dragPiece)
         }
        .offset(dragOffset)
    }
    init() {
        id = ""
        orientation = 0
    }
    init(id: String, orientation: Int = 0, gesture: String = "") {
        self.id = id
        self.orientation = orientation
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59540581/12299030, and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693584/12299030. For more look SO by `DragGesture` - there are a lot of working examples.

Comment: Thanks. I did look at many other examples of `DragGesture`, but I didn't find any examples where the same situation arose -- that is, where `onEnded` was never reached when `onChanged` was present.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `.offset(dragOffset)` must appear before `.gesture(dragPiece)`. The following code works as expected:

```
struct PieceView: View {
    var id: String
    @State private var orientation: Int
    @State private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State var selected = false
    var dragPiece: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                dragOffset = value.translation
                print("width: \(dragOffset.width), height: \(dragOffset.height)")
            }
            .onEnded{ value in
                print("\(id) dragged")
                dragOffset = value.translation
                print("width: \(dragOffset.width), height: \(dragOffset.height)")
            }
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(id + "\(orientation)")
            Image("boardSquare")
                .padding(0)
                .offset(dragOffset)
                .gesture(dragPiece)
         }
    }
    init() {
        id = ""
        orientation = 0
    }
    init(id: String, orientation: Int = 0, gesture: String = "") {
        self.id = id
        self.orientation = orientation
    }
}
```

In my case, this leaves me with some other UI design issues, because I want the gesture to apply to `Image("boardSquare")` but the whole `ZStack` to be dragged. But that's a separate issue, and at least now I know what the problem was with my current code.