# Constrain View while using DragGesture in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, draggesture

I am currently building a BeReal clone and I am working on the small picture you can drag across the screen.

Rectangle Code (Placeholder for small image)

```
Rectangle()
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.33,
           height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.44)
    .offset(smallOffset)
    .gesture(
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged({ changedValue in
                smallOffset = changedValue.translation
            })
            .onEnded({ _ in
                smallOffset = .zero
            })
    )
    .animation(.easeIn, value: 200)
```

Frame for ZStack

```
@State var smallOffset: CGSize = .zero

var body: some View{
    ZStack{
        ....
    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
           height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1.33)
}
```

The Drag Gesture is working, but it is allowed to go over the frame I have given. So is there any way I can prevent the rectangle to go over the frame I set for the entire ZStack

Essentially I want the Rectangle to disappear behind the rest of the things on the screen when it leaves the given frame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit drag to rectangle bounds in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72798277/limit-drag-to-rectangle-bounds-in-swiftui)